# How to use Linux command(sed?) to delete specific lines in a file?

Tags: linux, sed

I have a file that contains a matrix. For example, I have:

```
1 a  2  b
2 b  5  b
3 d  4  b
4 b  7  b
```

I know it's easy to use `sed` command to delete specific lines with specific strings. But what if I only want to delete those lines where the second field's value is b (i.e., second line and fourth line)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use regex in sed.

```
sed -i 's/^[0-9]\s+b.*//g' xxx_file
```

or

```
sed -i '/^[0-9]\s+b.*/d' xxx_file
```

The "-i" argument will modify the file's content directly, you can remove "-i" and output the result to other files as you want.

Comment: Hi, thanks. But can you tell me which field in the command specify the b should be at second field? I didn't see any value like "2"...

Comment: The way the regex works is that the `^` marks the start of the line; the `[0-9]` looks for a single digit; the `\s*` looks for zero or more space-like characters (if the version of `sed` you're using supports it, which on Linux is normally the case — beware on non-Linux systems, though), followed by a `b` (and then the `.*` matches anything else on the line).  The first command replaces all that with 'nothing', leaving you a blank line when there's a `b` in the second column; the second deletes the line (and really doesn't need the `.*` at the end of the regex).  _[...continued...]_

Comment: _[...continuation...]_ So, the regex matches the `b` in the second column (and doesn't match anything else in the sample data), but it isn't bullet proof.  It would delete a line `9b c 7 x` (because there can be zero spaces between the digit and the `b`.  It also would delete `9 bad 8 y`; it is not entirely clear whether your specification means that should be deleted or not.  Fixing those issues is far from impossible; it is not clear whether it is necessary either.

Comment: Just change the \s* to \s+ would work, or simply a white space. But it depends on Hao's requirements and I believe he can finish it by himself :) @Jonathan Thank you for the explaining of reflex :)

Comment: Error spelling…I hate the small keyboard on the iPhone -_-

Answer (score 1):

awk:

```
cat yourfile.txt | awk '{if($2!="b"){print;}}'
```

Comment: I suspect `$2 != "b"` would print the correct lines; the `==` condition prints the lines that should be deleted.  Also, you get a [UUOC Award](http://catb.org/jargon/html/U/UUOC.html).  You can and should use `awk '...' yourfile.txt`.

Comment: I love that page. cat "costs" me a process. How much did I pay for it?

Answer (score 1):

Awk just work fine, just use code as below:

```
awk '{if ($2 != "b") print $0;}' file
```

if you want get more usage about `awk`, just `man` it!